# How to remove bonded-printed content from a ripstop fabric?

Tags: cleaning, fabric, printing

I was gifted an insulated picnic bag (a bit like [this one](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ebGKF.jpg)). The thing is, its rip-stop fabric side has a company logo printed on it...

[image]

... and it doesn't just scratch off. How can I remove the printed logo without harming the fabric?

Answer (score 3):

The rubberized printing responds well to several applications of felt marker. In your case, choose a permanent marker in dark blue. Use a hatching stroke at 45 degree angle to completely cover the printing. If the marker touches the base fabric, it will not be too noticeable. Repeat this the next day or two. The colour does a good job of camouflaging the logo. I have done this method on T-shirt logos, usually black polypropylene. The marker fades a bit and can be touched up.

Answer (score 0):

One approach would be to avoid *removing* the logo, and rather, sew some kind of patch over it. Like maybe a RISC-V logo for good measure. Unfortunately, this would be non-trivial to do without puncturing the insulation - you would have to only pierce the fabric and not go any deeper, coming back out through it.